# How to fit a linear trendline to a semilog scatter plot in Libre Office Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have the plot below:

[image]

and I would like to fit linear trendlines to the data, so I can use the slope in further calculations. However, when I try to fit a linear trendline, I get this: 
[image]

If I fit a power trendline, then I get an R^2 over .999, but that trendline is useless to me... Does anyone know the proper way to accomplish this?

EDIT: Here is the data in CSV format

```
Iron in Copper,,,Cobalt in Copper,,,Nickel in Copper,,
T (oC),D (cm2/sec),1/T (1/K),T (oC),D (cm2/sec),1/T (1/K),T (oC),D (cm2/sec),1/T (1/K)
1074,5.65E-09,0.0007423078,1077,3.43E-09,0.0007406584,1076,1.98E-09,0.0007412074
974,1.11E-09,0.0008018282,983,7.64E-10,0.0007960833,980,3.57E-10,0.0007979891
895,2.86E-09,0.0008560544,904,1.77E-10,0.0008495094,900,7.87E-11,0.0008524059
830,7.80E-11,0.000906495,844,5.09E-11,0.0008951349,847,2.61E-11,0.0008927376
780,2.67E-11,0.0009495324,793,1.65E-11,0.0009379543,791,6.82E-12,0.0009397171
719,6.55E-12,0.0010079121,744,5.31E-12,0.0009831392,743,1.90E-12,0.0009841067
,,,701,1.76E-12,0.001026536,,,
```

Comment: Your y-Axis is in logarithmic scale. So for sure the linear trend line will look like you see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm - with those values, i get:

[image]

The trend lines seem fine for me? (Sorry, no answer, but i can't put the chart into a comment...)

Comment: Thank you for responding; I figured the issue out. I misunderstood the assignment and am actually supposed to use exponential trend lines.